# return dict items from a python function

Tags: python, json, function, dictionary, return

Is there a way for a function to return just the key value pairs in Python without the dict itself?

return {"_meta": {"hostvars": {}}, "group":Tags}

## returns

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {}
  },
  "group": {
    "Env_Prod": [
      "1.1.1.1"
    ],
    "Logstash": [
      "2.2.2.2"
    ] } }

#Trying to have it return.
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {}
  },
    "Env_Prod": [
      "1.1.1.1"
    ],
    "Logstash": [
      "2.2.2.2"
    ] }
```

Comment: You've posted a bunch of (incorrectly-indented) code, but you haven't asked a question.

Comment: My Apologies, I am new to posting questions on Stackoverflow, I just corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood it correctly, Tags is a dict, and you want to merge it into your other dict, so:

```py
d1 = {"_meta": {"hostvars": {}}}
return {**d1, **Tags}
```

Tell me if it worked.

Comment: Happy to read it, I apreciate if you could accept as the awnser, to help with my badges :)

Comment: I should just click on the pass Symbol right:, I just did....Can you also please up vote the question to help with my badge....